# Aireplay-ng broadcast doesn't work on a client

Tags: aircrack-ng

Launching Deauth attacks on my BSSID disconnects all devices except one. I figured out that in order to make it work I have to use the -c command to specifically deauth that client, but is there any way to deauth it by attacking the BSSID? I've confirmed that the device is connected to the correct network.
ps: The device that can't be deauthenticated is a Windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 1):

[Why does deauthentication not work?](https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=deauthentication):

> Some clients ignore broadcast deauthentications. If this is the case,
>   you will need to send a deauthentication directed at the particular
>   client.

I see nothing else to be added to this.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I needed to know. And for anyone in the future, it is possible to use broadcast and at the same time a specific client.